# ImportError: No module named sklearn.preprocessing

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ubuntu-14.04

I installed scikit-learn successfully on Ubuntu following these [instructions](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/install.html#install-official-release).

However, I get this error when I run a program that uses it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "begueradj.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
ImportError: No module named sklearn.preprocessing
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

The instructions given in that tutorial you linked to are obsolete for Ubuntu 14.04.

The Ubuntu 14.04 package is named python-sklearn (formerly `python-scikits-learn`):

```
sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```

The `python-sklearn` package is in the default repositories in Ubuntu 14.04 as well as in other currently supported Ubuntu releases.

Comment: The same issue got fixed in Ubuntu 17.04 too.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by running this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```

Comment: This had already been suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29229618/4685471) 3 years before; please do not add duplicate answers.